# Best way to create a grid of TouchableOpacity items with different callbacks?

Tags: android, react-native

I have an app where I want to show a list of images as a grid with the first element on the list being an "add"-button. I also need every image to be Touchable. Currently my code looks like this:

```
class RNtest extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            counter: 0 //Used to give unique numbers to the items
        };
    }

    itemPicker() {
        var temp = this.state.data;
        temp.push({text: this.state.counter});
        this.setState({
            data: temp,
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    }

    onPress() {
        console.warn('YO!');
    }

    render()  {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.body}>

                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>ITEMS</Text>

                    <View style={styles.gallery}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.addButton}
                            onPress={this.itemPicker.bind(this)}
                        >
                            <Text>ADD</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        {this.state.data.map(function(item) {
                            return (
                                <TouchableOpacity
                                    style={styles.item}
                                    onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
                                >
                                        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            );
                        })}
                    </View>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}
```

The stylesheet in case someone needs it:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    addButton: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 72,
        width: 72,
        borderRadius: 2,
        marginVertical: 6,
        marginRight: 6,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    gallery: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    item: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#DCFFC2',
        height: 72,
        width: 72,
        borderRadius: 2,
        margin: 6
    },
    section: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        paddingTop: 10
    },
    sectionHeader: {
        fontSize: 13,
        fontWeight: '400',
        paddingBottom: 1,
        color: '#A7A7A7'
    },
    body: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
        paddingVertical: 10,
        paddingHorizontal: 20
    },
});
```

Obviously the onPress function doesn't work because apparently `this` is not visible inside the for-loop.

I could use ListView but then inside renderRow I would have to check if the item to be rendered is the add button, and it would make a few other parts more difficult as well.

Could I use refs in this situation, and is it a good idea?

I'm running React Native 0.27.2 on Android emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only the problem you're having at the moment is scope-related, this can best be corrected by specifying a scope for your `map` function that processes your `this.state.data`. However I see a couple of other issues to comment on with your code.

1. Your `itemPicker` function is directly mutating your state via the `push` function. Opt for using a function such as `concat` which will return a new array (or the spread operator). Refer to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) for reasons why you shouldn't directly mutate state like this.
2. Make sure you add a unique `key` to the resulting `TouchableOpacity` items you're creating (see warnings from React)

I've modified your code sample to demonstrate these concepts:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity,
    View
} from 'react-native';

class RNTest extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            counter: 0
        };
    }

    itemPicker() {
        // 'push' will mutate, concat will return a new array
        this.setState({
            data: this.state.data.concat({text: this.state.counter}),
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    }

    createButton (item, index) {
        // add a unique key, per react warnings
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={index}
                style={styles.item}
                onPress={this.onPress}>
                    <Text>{item.text}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    onPress() {
        console.warn('YO!');
    }

    render()  {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={styles.body}>

                <View style={styles.section}>
                    <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>ITEMS</Text>

                    <View style={styles.gallery}>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            style={styles.addButton}
                            onPress={this.itemPicker.bind(this)}
                        >
                            <Text>ADD</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        {this.state.data.map(this.createButton, this)}
                    </View>
                </View>

            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}

export default RNTest;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully. I haven't got a lot of experience with React Native so I'm glad you also pointed out some of my other mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using arrow function:

```
{this.state.data.map((item) => {
    // your code
})}
```

Or you could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
{this.state.data.map(function(item) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.item}
            onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
        >
        <Text>{item.text}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}.bind(this))}
```

What both solutions do is passing the `this` parameter to inside your loop.